# Consume ssl soap with java

Tags: java, ssl, soap

i am new to web services , i  have 2  simple java projects(maven) , one is the service and other is the client, i just need to consume this using soap ssl.This is my web service (interface+implementation):

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface CalculService {

@WebMethod
@WebResult
public int test(int val1, int val2);
}
///// impl///
@WebService(endpointInterface = 
 "wstest.CalculService")

public class CalculImpl implements CalculService {

public int test(int val1, int val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
}
}
```

now after googling for hours i couldnt find something easy to understand, so i found this code below which seemed not complicated :

```
public class ClientSoap {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Code to make a webservice HTTP request
    String responseString = "";
    String outputString = "";
    String wsEndPoint = "http://localhost:8883/myservice";
    URL url = new URL(wsEndPoint);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String xmlInput = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
            + "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body> <generaleRequest xmlns=\"http://wstest/CalculService/\"><arg0>50</arg0>"
            + "</generaleRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlInput.length()];
    buffer = xmlInput.getBytes();
    bout.write(buffer);
    byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
    String SOAPAction = "generale";
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(b.length));
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    // Write the content of the request to the outputstream of the HTTP
    // Connection.
    out.write(b);
    out.close();
    // Ready with sending the request.
    // Read the response.
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    // Write the SOAP message response to a String.
    while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outputString = outputString + responseString;
    }
    // Write the SOAP message formatted to the console.
    String formattedSOAPResponse = formatXML(outputString);
    System.out.println(formattedSOAPResponse);
}

// format the XML in pretty String
private static String formatXML(String unformattedXml) {
    try {
        Document document = parseXmlFile(unformattedXml);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 3);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, xmlOutput);
        return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

// parse XML
private static Document parseXmlFile(String in) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(in));
        return db.parse(is);
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Please i didndt know what to put in this 2 lignes:
1-String wsEndPoint = "http://localhost:8883/myservice";

2- String xmlInput = "

-does every soap i want to consume via ssl i need to use XML? please guys excuse my noobism in web services.
or if this code not good , can u guys give me THE SIMPLEST CODE to consume a soap web service via ssl? for total beginner. thank you

Comment: The fact that you need XML tooling comes from SOAP, not "SSL". SSL aka TLS since 20 years deals with transports, not serialization. SOAP is based of XML typically for services over HTTP(s). But you shouldn't have to deal with that, you should use a proper SOAP library for your programming language, in order to properly generate and parse SOAP messages. Same for WSDL that sits "on top" of SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

please someone just tell me what to put at (1-String wsEndPoint=???) and (String xmlInput =").
Or just give me easiest code to consume soap via ssl with https please